# React native: NPM fails to install react-navigation (not in npm registry)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-navigation

I'm trying to install `react-navigation`, but can't figure out why npm/yarn fails to retrieve a dependency (npm http fetch GET 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/@react-navigation%2fnative 1193ms)

This is the full log. Any thoughts?

```
npm install #finishes OK

npm install --save-dev react-navigation

npm info using npm@6.8.0
npm info using node@v11.3.0
npm verb npm-session 7dacdbc55ea7d70c
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-navigation 24ms (from cache)
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 1708ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 11ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 880ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-navigation-drawer 29ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-navigation-tabs 30ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/@react-navigation%2fcore 33ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/react-navigation-stack 36ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/@react-navigation%2fnative 1193ms
npm http fetch GET 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/@react-navigation%2fnative 1135ms
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 4939ms
npm verb stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/@react-navigation%2fnative - Not Found
npm verb stack     at res.buffer.catch.then.body (/check-response.js:104:15)
npm verb stack     at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
npm verb statusCode 404
```

Comment: It is still inaccessible?

Comment: @adnbsr It is, yes.

Comment: try to remove node modules and re install

Comment: @AkilaDevinda Same result